# How to use Knockout's data-bind attribute in Mvc helpers like Html.EditorFor()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I tried this 
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, " ", new { data_bind = "value:firstName" });`
and other possible overloades but none of them seem to work.

The rest of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function AppViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("");
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

Comment: I would recommend of just using generic html and not use the @html.Editor helper.  If you need the data from the model, use that to build your AppViewModel

Comment: What is the html output that your editor creates? Does it create a textbox or label? Is it missing the data-bind attribute that you specified?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your 3rd parameter to `EditorFor` does not do what you think it should be doing.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406461(v=vs.98).aspx

`EditorFor` cannot add HTML attributes to the element. Use `TextBoxFor` instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { data_bind = "value:firstName" });
```

Comment: For .Net Framework 4.6.1 and up I can confirm that `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: firstName", maxlength = 50 } });` works. **data_bind** is still key!

Answer (score 1):

I understand I'm a bit late on this one, but here's a solution I've been using.

Pass the name of the field (in this case `name`) to the editor template as part of the `additionalViewData` like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(t => t.name, "", new { fieldName = "name" })
```

Then in your `editorTemplate` you can have this:

```
@{
    var fieldName = ViewData.Where(v => v.Key == "fieldName").FirstOrDefault().Value;
}
@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { data_bind = "value:"+fieldName })
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Make sure you use the markup to [properly format code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). It greatly helps with readability.